# Split a string with '\n', insert it into UITableViewCell and get height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, multiline

I'm developing an iOS 4 application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I use a web service to retrieve some text data. I don't know its length so I will need to split that strings to fit inside a custom `UITableViewCell`.

This custom `UITableViewCell` will have an `UILabel`. And this label will be filled up with the text retrieved from web service.

The text will be country names: *Spain, France, USA, Italy, etc.* I will process this names to append them to a **unique** string. I will do it this way: *"Spain - France - USA - ..."*.

One of my problems was that this line could be so long, and I need to split it into lines to fits `UILabel` width. I have solve this problem, checking every time I add a ' - ' if the string will get bigger than UILabel width. So, I will have a string like this: *"Spain - France\nUSA - ...".*

Ok. Now, I have a string with **\n** that will fit inside UILabel. So, I will need to modify `UITableViewCell` height to fits with `UILabel` height.

But, when I use `[NSString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize]];` I'm not getting the real height, I'm always getting 21.0f.

I've found this [tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/) about UITableView Dynamic Height, but I don't know how to use it with my code.

**In a nutshell**, I need to append **' - '** character to country names, but it there is a return carried (because the string will be rendered in another line by UILabel), I don't have to append **' - '**. And, when I get this string, I will have to resize custom `UITableViewCell` to `UILabel` height.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that something you are looking for?

```
//create a CGFloat variable
CGFloat _height = 0;
//find out the size for your text. Instead of 255 insert the width of your label
CGSize _textSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize] constrainedToSize:(CGSize) { 255, 9999 }];
//add the height of that CGSize variable to your height in case you will need to add more values
_height += _textSize.height;
//eventually some other calculations
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and I'll tell you.

Comment: @VansFannel it is the piece of code from my project, it did work a few months ago :)